# C++ class filler syntax error

Tags: c++

My class is as follows:

> class stats {
>
> public:     int strength,
> perception,endurance,charisma,inteligence,agility,luck,health,stamina,mana,karma;
>
> };

As far as I know, there shouldn't be anything wrong with it, unless I need to set up a constructor and destructor.

I create my object using the following line:

> stats* mainstat=new stats;

And I have the following function to "fill" objects of the said class:

> void statfiller(stats* object, int table[]){
>
> object->strength=table[0]; object->perception=table[1];
> object->endurance=table[2]; object->charisma=table[3];
> object->inteligence=table[4]; object->agility=table[5];
> object->luck=table[6]; object->health=table[7];
> object->stamina=table[8]; object->mana=table[9];
> object->karma=table[10];
>
> }

So, until then, no problem. At least, until the following:

I create a table with the data to fill, then feed it to my fill function.

> int tablet[10]; tablet[0]=5; tablet[1]=5; tablet[2]=5; tablet[3]=5;
> tablet[4]=5; tablet[5]=5; tablet[6]=5; tablet[7]=50; tablet[8]=50;
> tablet[9]=50; tablet[10]=0;
>
> statfiller(mainstat*,tablet);

When I do this, a compiling error comes up, stating the syntax of my function is incorrect.

Why is it so? Do I need to use pointer(*) or address(&)? Is there something I'm missing?

Odds are, the solution is very simple, but at the moment of typing this, I just don't see what's wrong with it ^^;

Comment: remove the * after mainstat. statfiller(mainstat*,tablet);
Also if you post the error it would help check the code thats causing the error.

Comment: The error code from the compiler was "[BCC32 Erreur] Unit1.cpp(445): E2188 Syntaxe de l'expression"
Removing the pointer, as you stated, solved the issue. Thank you. Which makes sense - the function calls for a reference to the object, that's why the pointer is there.

Comment: After you do what @user3279954 suggested you may want to contemplate the effect of stashing eleven items in a ten element array, and on the stack to boot.

Comment: Actually yeah thanks

Comment: Cheers, that's fixed too.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem was the following:

The function's syntax is "void statfiller(stats* object, int table[]) ", where the stats* object serves as reference, pointer to an object of stats class.

In the function's call "statfiller(mainstat*,tablet);", the mistake I made was calling a pointer of a stat object (in this case mainstat) instead of just putting in the object.